# How to find lost image in uv/image editor?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I was rendering my model in cycles render, and I zoomed out and panned away (in the uv/image editor), and now I can't find the rendered image. How do I center it in the image editor?

Comment: use the "Home" key. Alternatively, you can also save it to disk (even if not visible).

Comment: If you're in object mode `Shift C` should get it back into view.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

<kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>View Fit</kbd>
Or <kbd>View All</kbd>

Or use a hotkey like lemon mentioned (provided you are using blender's default hotkeys):

<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>

[image]